# Jitbit helpdesk References and experiences

Tags: ticket-system

Does anyone out there have any experience with Jitbit Helpdesk?  My comapny is looking to replace our current Ticketing system due to costs.  We have run the basic company searches such as DNB, without much luck (guessing due to the size of the developer's company).

We plan on using the system with approximately 100 users, and have a dedicated IT department to support and modify the code to fit our needs.

My company is willing to go with a smaller provider (we will be self hosting) but have been trying to find companies of our size or larger that use this software to get their take on it, both good and bad.

If you have experience with this ticketing system I would appreciate your feedback, both good and bad.

My company would prefer to do a reference call, but even some good honest feedback from the users at Stack Overflow could turn the tide one way or the other.

My alternative would be to start Googling JitBit, find companies using the hosted version, then trying to call their IT departments until I find someone that could possibly share their experiences,  (That sounds absolutely horrible to even attempt, but I'm fighting a large compliance and purchasing department).

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you looking for a comparison between Jitbit Helpdesk against your current solution or just against other current competitors?

Comment: I'm looking for opinions of individuals that have or are using it now for their helpdesk functions.

Likes, dislikes, wishes, challenges, that kind of thing.

Comment: Alex from Jitbit here. As flattered as I am, those questions are still off-topic at SO :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes into this thread with the same question, I just wanted to check back and let you all know how it went.

We did purchase the Jitbit software, and after some code modifications (we purchased the license with source code) it works extremely well.

Some caveats:
The system is more geared towards helpdesks that accept external callers versus an internal corporate helpdesk, and there are no group based permissions they are all handled on a user basis.  I had to write the group security by co-opting their department assignments and writing some custom permission code, but for the price(~2k/year versus 100k/year), we are extremely happy with it.